# What is wrong with my andengine-gles2

Tags: java, eclipse, andengine

When I import `andengine-gles2` project to my game I still get following errors:

```
import org.andengine.entity.primitive.Ellipse;
import org.andengine.entity.primitive.Mesh.DrawMode;
import org.andengine.entity.primitive.Vector2;
```

What else I should import or do?

Comment: I dont see any error only imports.

Comment: Yes you cant see it because I cant post it yet. I import andengin-gles2 libary... and import list is long but i wrote only 3 of these that have error.

Comment: It is possible that you are using a new andengine library from GitHub and using and old tutorial? Vector2 is not present in GLES2 branch.

Comment: sm4 yes exactly. It is not new project... What I should do? Use gles1?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an old tutorial with a new library. I wouldn't recommend using an old library as well (e.g. GLES1). If you really insist on keeping the old code, try removing the imports and simply let the IDE to import missing classes again. But the classes might not be available at all.

You can also try to understand the tutorial and rewrite it using the new libraries.

Note that AndEngine is pretty much dead and there isn't any serious development going on. You might want to reconsider your engine choice. If you really want to use AndEngine, use GLES-AnchorCenter branch. It's the newest one.